# How to combine different pidstat outputs (CPU, I/O, Disk Usage)

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, iowait

I would like to use *pidstat* to get both -u, -r and -d flags. Is there a way to do so?

The idea, is to get both CPU, I/O and disk usage.

Cheers

Ps. Combining the flags as -urd doesn't work in Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add the `-h` flag. This display all activities horizontally on a single line.

`pidstat -urd -h`

Comment: Thanks man, this is awesome! :-) Btw never paid too much attention to that very useful flag!